# API/Command to get reason for machine requiring reboot

Tags: c++, winapi

In the Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager, there is a column indicating if a system requires restart and the reason for the restart.
[image: MECM screenshot]
I am able to find if a system requires reboot using [get_RebootRequired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-isysteminformation-get_rebootrequired). But I am not able to find the reason for the restart as displayed in the image.

```
VARIANT_BOOL
        bRebootRequired;
    info->get_RebootRequired(&bRebootRequired);
```

Is there an API/command which I can use to get that information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/449982/apicommand-to-get-reason-for-machine-requiring-reb.html

The answer for this is explained in this

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for:
[RM_REBOOT_REASON enumeration (restartmanager.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/ne-restartmanager-rm_reboot_reason)

| Reason | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| RmRebootReasonNone | A system restart is not required. |
| RmRebootReasonPermissionDenied | The current user does not have sufficient privileges to shut down one or more processes. |
| RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch | One or more processes are running in another Terminal Services session. |
| RmRebootReasonCriticalProcess | A system restart is needed because one or more processes to be shut down are critical processes. |
| RmRebootReasonCriticalService | A system restart is needed because one or more services to be shut down are critical services. |
| RmRebootReasonDetectedSelf | A system restart is needed because the current process must be shut down. |

You may also refer to:
[Restart Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/restart-manager-portal)

**EDIT:**

For more details, you may use the [Shutdown Event Tracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutdown-event-tracker)

The reasons are defined in [System Shutdown Reason Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-reason-codes).

Comment: I am looking for a more specific reason, like "windows Update" or "configuration change"
@PalLaden